# Replace spark dataframe column value with random value (ex. UUID)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with column user_tag which I would like to have new random UUID values, how can I do that?

```
--------------------------------------
| user_tag  |  pref_code  |  name    |
--------------------------------------
| abc123    |  Reg        |  Richard |
| abc123    |  Reg        |  Mort    |
| abc123    |  Disc       |  Jack    |
```

I want to generate randomUUID for user_tag in spark. To have

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| user_tag                                |  pref_code  |  name    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| af3fb8b8-7ceb-4cec-ac27-2a034bb44bb9    |  Reg        |  Richard |
| snc22fls-2cgb-sas2-hc26-43d35ggg4522    |  Reg        |  Mort    |
| afgdw8b8-4fss-ycec-ycd7-haj3jbbj4bj9    |  Disc       |  Jack    |
```

I tried this: but it results in the same UUID for each row

```
val withUUID = dataFrame.withColumn("user_tag", 
  when(col("user_tag") === "abc123", randomUUID.toString).otherwise(col("user_tag")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by creating **`udf`** then call the udf inside **`case when-then statement`**.

***Example:***

```
val rand_UUID = udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString) //udf to generate randomUUID

val df=Seq(("abc123","Reg","Richard"),("abc123","Reg","Mort"))
       .toDF("user_tag","pref_code","name")

df.withColumn("user_tag",when('user_tag === "abc123",rand_UUID())
  .otherwise('user_tag))
  .show(false)
```

***Result:***

```
+------------------------------------+---------+-------+
|user_tag                            |pref_code|name   |
+------------------------------------+---------+-------+
|e0b3c917-dcc5-4c42-bfe3-32af18b1cfec|Reg      |Richard|
|90098d7d-8dc7-42df-a89b-5bd7f2c5cd99|Reg      |Mort   |
+------------------------------------+---------+-------+
```

Basically everymatch will call udf then generate `randomUUID`.